# grpc-dart - how to set the HEADER in grpc-dart - I can only do it via a secure connection

Tags: kubernetes, dart, grpc, cert-manager

Running a container in k8s with cert-manager to issue a Letsencrypt certificate. 
The security between the client and the container is alright, so I dont need to use any further TLS code between the client and the server container - right?

I need to set the `curl -H "Host:` in grpc-dart, but I can only do it via a secure connection in the grpc-dart code:

```
final channel = new ClientChannel('mydomain.com', // localhost
    port: 80,
    options: const ChannelOptions(
        credentials: const ChannelCredentials.secure(authority: "some header"))
        );
```

Is there anyway around this, as I would like to NOT use any more TLS than I already have with k8s and cert-manager?

Thanks

Comment: Your question title makes it sound like a different problem, you can probably get better help with a better title. Your last sentence there gives better context.

Comment: Thanks @cookiedough

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `ChannelCredentials.insecure({String? authority})`:

```dart
final channel = new ClientChannel('mydomain.com', // localhost
    port: 80,
    options: const ChannelOptions(
        credentials: const ChannelCredentials.insecure(authority: "some header"))
        );
```

Docs: https://pub.dev/documentation/grpc/latest/grpc/ChannelCredentials/ChannelCredentials.insecure.html